# Run Jest test suites in groups

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, supertest

I am writing extensive tests for a new API via Jest and supertest. Prior to running the tests, I am setting up a test database and populating it with users:

#### Test command

```
jest --forceExit --config src/utils/testing/jest.config.js
```

#### File *jest.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: process.cwd(),

  // Sets up testing database with users
  globalSetup: './src/utils/testing/jest.setup.js',

  // Ensures connection to database for all test suites
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: './src/utils/testing/jest.db.js',

}
```

So I am starting with a database of some users to test on. The problem is this:

Some of my tests rely upon the success of other tests. In this application, users can upload images, and group them into packs. So my grouping endpoint suite depends upon the success of my image upload suite, and so on.

I am well aware many people might say this is bad practice, and that tests should not rely upon other tests. That being said, I would really rather keep all my tests via `supertest`, and not get into dependency injection, etc. I don't want to have to meticulously set up testing conditions (for example, creating a bunch of user images artificially before running the tests), because: (1) this is just duplication of logic, and (2) it increases the possibility of something breaking.

Is there any way to group jest suites? For example, to run suites in order:

```
jest run creationSuite
jest run modificationSuite
```

This way, all my "creationSuite" tests could be run simultaneously, and success of *all* would then trigger the "modificationSuite" to run, etc., in a fail-fast manner.

Alternatively, specifying inside a test suite dependencies on other test suites would be great:

```
describe('Grouping endpoint', () => {
    // Somehow define dependencies
    this.dependsOn(uploadSuite)
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use `jest-runner-groups` to define and run tests in groups. Once it's installed and added to the Jest configuration, you can tag your tests using docblock notation, like here:

```js
/**
 * Foo tests
 *
 * @group group1/subgroup1
 * @group unit/foo
 */

describe( 'Foo class', () => {
    ...
} );
```

```js
/**
 * Bar tests
 *
 * @group group1/subgroup2
 * @group unit/bar
 */

describe( 'Bar class', () => {
    ...
} );
```

Update your jest configuration to specify a new runner:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    runner: "groups"
};
```

Then to run a specific group, you need to use `--group=` argument:

```
// Using the Jest executable
jest --group=mygroup

// Or npm
npm test -- --group=mygroup
```

You can also use multiple `--group` arguments to run multiple groups:

```
// Will execute tests in the unit/bar and unit/foo groups
npm test -- --group=unit/bar --group=unit/foo

// Will execute tests in the unit group (including unit/bar and unit/foo groups)
npm test -- --group=unit
```

Comment: The package does not work with jest-expo preset :/

Comment: What happens with the tests that don't have any group annotations? Do they get ignored during a group run? Or if one runs just `jest` does it also run all groups?

Answer (score 13):

I have done it with the `--testNamePattern` flag. Here is the procedure.

Let’s say that you have two groups of tests:

- `DevTest` for testing in development environment
- `ProdTest` for testing in production environemnt

If you want to test only those features required for the development environment, you have to add `DevTest` to the test description:

```js
describe('(DevTest): Test in development environment', () => {
  // Your test
})

describe('(ProdTest): Test in production environment', () => {
  // Your test
})

describe('Test everywhere', () => {
  // Your test
})
```

After that, you can add commands to your `package.json` file:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:prod": "jest --testNamePattern=ProdTest",
    "test:dev": "jest --testNamePattern=DevTest",
    "test:update": "jest --updateSnapshot"
  }
```

Command `npm test` will run *all* of your tests, since you are not using flag `--testNamePattern`. If you want to run other tests, just use `npm run test:dev` for example.

Be careful when naming your test groups though. They are searched with regex in test description and you don't want this command to match other words.

Answer (score 2):

Jest test suites are executed in multiple threads, and this is one of its main benefits. Test runs can be completed much faster this way, but the test sequence isn't preserved by design.

It's possible to disable this feature with the [`runInBand`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#runinband) option.

It's possible to pick tests and suites based on their names with the `testNamePattern` option or based on their paths with [`testPathPattern` option](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#testpathpattern-regex).

Since one suite depends on another one, they possibly could be combined into a single suite in the order they are expected to run. They can still reside in different files (make sure they aren't matched by Jest), e.g.:

```
// foobar.test.js
describe(..., () => {
  require('foo.partial-test.js');
  require('bar.partial-test.js');
});
```

> The problem is this:
>
> Some of my tests rely upon the success of other tests.

This is the real problem here. The approach that relies on previous a test state is considered flawed in any kind of automated tests.

> I don't want to have to meticulously set up testing conditions (for example, creating a bunch of user images artificially before running the tests), because: (1) this is just duplication of logic, and (2) it increases the possibility of something breaking.

There is no need to set up testing conditions (fixtures) artificially. Fixtures can be extracted from existing environment, even from the results of your current tests if you're sure about their quality.

- Redundancy and tautology naturally occur in automated tests, there's nothing wrong with them. Tests can be made DRYer with proper management of fixtures and shared code.
- Quite the contrary, errors are always accumulated. A test that created faulty prerequisites may pass, but another test will fail, thus creating a debugging conundrum.

Comment: "There is no need to set up testing conditions (fixtures) artificially. Fixtures can be extracted from existing environment, even from the results of your current tests if you're sure about their quality." - Can you say more about this please?

Comment: E.g. if your case is DB testing and you need to have non-empty DB, you can get some existing records from your DB that satisfy the testcase, save them to .sql fixture and restore in beforeEach. Since your case is API testing, you likely need to dump real API responses to files and mock HTTP with Nock.

Comment: Exactly my point. Those mock files would need to be updated every time there is a "footprint" change to the API. That's what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: This is usually the right thing to do, even though it's cumbersome. Tests become predictable this way. Any way, the first part of the answer  addresses the question itself, these are the way this is possible. I'd go with a hierarchy of suites and .partial-test.js because multithreading is valuable Jest feature that shouldn't be discarded for nothing.

Comment: Sorry, what is partial-test.js?

Comment: See the code in the answer. I suppose that this will work even without wrapper `describe(..., () => {` code, so `require` could be replaced with `import`, but I'm not sure about that, this depends on how Jest does multithreading.