# Any recommended ways to execute Jest tests sequentially, in a predefined order?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, integration

I am interested in using Jest for integration tests, not just unit tests. To do this, I'm exploring ways to get Jest scripts to execute in a specified order.

I've tried a suggestion from a related post (see link below) and it works: create separate files (that don't end in .test) for each test (or group of tests), import them into the main App.test.js, and call the files in the desired order. 
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6194#issuecomment-419837314

`App.test.js`

```
import { apptestgroup1 } from './apptests.set1'
import { apptestgroup2 } from './apptests.set2'
import { apptestgroup3 } from './apptests.set3'

describe('App tests Group 1', apptestgroup1)
describe('App tests Group 2', apptestgroup2)
describe('App tests Group 3', apptestgroup3)
```

`apptests.set1.js`

```
export const apptestgroup1 = () => {
  it('sets loggedInUser = false when logOut is called', () => {});
  it('renders <Home /> when logOut is called', () => {});
}
```

`apptests.set2.js`

```
(more tests, similar to above)
```

`apptests.set3.js`

```
(more tests, similar to above)
```

Comment: It may be not a good idea to do that because running tests in parallel is one of Jest's selling points. If these are integration tests, consider grouping them in independent suites. There's `runInBand` Jest option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run jest test suites in groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171932/run-jest-test-suites-in-groups)

Comment: I thought runInBand didn't allow you to specify order? It only allows the list of tests to be specified but Jest decides the order.