# How do i keep a single variable(Access Token) accessed by all test suits in JEST Test?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am new to jest testing and I am trying to find a way to access the access token for all test-suites in my project. I have tried global variable and the setup files of jest but nothing worked for me.

I tried keeping all in one describe like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174429/11883120)  but how can I mention only the folder name rather than file name in it?

How can I write my access token into an empty file present in my project and access that inside my test suits?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to use common data for Jest.
Make a separate file containing whatever you need.

Then in the test file do this:

`const TESTDATA = require("./test_data/auth-key.json");`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even I have a constant file but it doesn't store my access-token for all test suites it only stores for single test suite in which I have initialized

Comment: I didn't understand. Please clarify a bit more

Comment: maybe you can write a script that obtain the token and store the token in a json file, and you can put this script in the setupFilesAfterEnv https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array area of the module.export object in the jest.config.js file

Comment: @AndreaBisello yes that's what I tried and it worked thanks